# Give a parent li a background image?

Tags: jquery

what im trying to do is give the parent li of a ul a background image.

so i have a submenu within a menu.

this is the jquery i am attempting..

```
$('li.on').closest('ul').parent('li').css({ backgroundImage: 'url(/content/images/point.png)', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }); ;
```

i think im going wrong at the parent bit?

this is the menu...

```
<div class="sideMenu2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href>retail</a>
           <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                <li ><a href="/portfolio/5/0">cabot circus</a></li>
                <li><a href="/portfolio/6/0">st. stephen&#39;s</a></li>
                <li><a href="/portfolio/7/0">silverburn</a></li>
                <li><a href="/portfolio/8/0">the elements</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href>sports &amp; leisure</a>
           <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                 <li class= "on"><a href="/portfolio/19/0">test</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

so if i click on test, sports and leisure should get the background, but currently retail is.

Comment: For the markup you've shown us, what it's doing is correct.  The li with class "on" is in retail, not sports & leisure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason retail is getting it because right at the beginning of the jquery expression you've written you have `$('li.on')`. This is selecting an `li` under retail so when it is going up its affecting retail.

You will need to get that first jquery expression right to get the right target. This may be as simple as changing it to `$(this)` if it is in a click handler but exactly what you do will depend on the context.

Comment: sorry the li changes when you click on text so that test is on, but retail is still being given the background

Comment: Did you try using `$(this)` anyway? It may be that there is a race condition between changing the class and the above code running such that it is picking up the wrong place but by the time you check it has reset it. If you have the anchor you clicked on (which I assume you do) then there is no need to go searching for the li again if you are always in it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to bind the `click` handler. It’s also important to prevent the default action in case the user clicks on the anchor (`<a>`).

```
$('li.on a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('ul').parent('li').css({
    'backgroundImage': 'url(/content/images/point.png)',
    'backgroundRepeat': 'no-repeat'
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qHUT4/